# keep getting "Null check operator used on a null value" error. i've checked my code 100 times

Tags: flutter, dart, nullpointerexception

keep getting "Null check operator used on a null value" error
actually im trying to use providers to get values from database and use em in my app
but im stuck at this i checked my code in every single way but still i keep getting this error

:lib\providers\user_provider.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:test_app/models/user.dart';
import 'package:test_app/resources/auth_methods.dart';

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

lib\pages\home.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:test_app/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:test_app/models/user.dart' as model;

// import 'dart:html';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addData();
  }

   addData() async {
     UserProvider _userProvider =
         Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
     await _userProvider.refreshUser();
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    model.User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("this is homepage"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

debug snippet

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building Home(dirty, dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<UserProvider?>], state: _HomeState#17895):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Home Home:file:///C:/Users/abc/Desktop/flutter/test_app/lib/main.dart:53:34

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      UserProvider.getUser (package:test_app/providers/user_provider.dart:9:28)
#1      _HomeState.build (package:test_app/pages/home.dart:36:59)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4735:5)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:11)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
#9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3524:20)
#11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#12     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#14     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#15     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#16     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#17     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#18     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#19     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:862:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
```

idk what the problem actually im new to flutter and dart
i've using python for my whole life

Answer (score 1):

`refreshUser` is a future and it sets `_user` but because you're calling `getUser` ***IMMEDIATELY build method***, which basically returns `_user` as a non-null value, the error would be thrown.

Try this:

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User? get getUser => _user;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And your `_HomeState`:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addData();
  }

   addData() async {
     UserProvider _userProvider =
         Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
     await _userProvider.refreshUser();
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    model.User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("this is homepage"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nah it didn't worked for but

Comment: Oh sorry, I made an edit, please check again...I removed `!`

Comment: @RajTripathi....

Answer (score 0):

In User_Provider.dart,
instead of doing:

```
 User get getUser => _user!;
```

Do this:

```
User? get getUser => _user;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).